# Getting an error "has no method 'contains'"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the following code snippet:

```
console.log(config.url);
if (config.method === 'GET' && config.url.contains("/Retrieve")) {
```

It outputs:

```
/Content/app/home/partials/menu.html app.js:255
TypeError: Object /Content/app/home/partials/menu.html has no method 'contains'
    at request (http://127.0.0.1:81/Content/app/app.js:256:59)
```

However this is giving me and error with the word ".contains". Anyone have any idea why I am getting this message?

```
has no method 'contains'
```

Does anyone have any idea why I might be getting this message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in JavaScript, strings don't have a `contains` method. You can use `indexOf`:

```
if (config.method === 'GET' && config.url.indexOf("/Retrieve") !== -1) {
```

Note that that's case-sensitive. To do it without worrying about capitalization, you can either use `toLowerCase()`:

```
if (config.method === 'GET' && config.url.toLowerCase().indexOf("/retrieve") !== -1) {
```

...or a regular expression with the `i` flag (case-**I**nsensitive):

```
if (config.method === 'GET' && config.url.match(/\/Retrieve/i)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that contains is a jQuery function so you can apply it only on jQuery objects.

If you want to use pure javascript you have to use indexOf function

Answer (score 1):

*contains()* is not a native JavaScript method; it's used by JS libraries such as jQuery though.

If you're just using pure JavaScript then you could use a method such as [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).